# How can I infer a type based on static string values for a higher-order function?

Tags: typescript, types

How can I map static string values (for a collection name) to a specific return type?

```
type Apple = {
  color: string
  taste: string
}

type Banana = {
  color: string
  length: string
}

type Carrot = {
  color: string
  baby: boolean
}

function collection(collectionName: string) {
  return function get() {
    switch (collectionName) {
      case 'apples':
        return [{
          color: 'red',
          taste: 'great',
        }];

      case 'bananas':
        return [{
          color: 'yellow',
          length: 'medium',
        }];

      case 'carrots':
        return [{
          color: 'orange',
          baby: false,
        }];
    }
  }
}
```

For example, in usage, I want it to infer that a specific collection name (`"apples"`) will return an array of a specific type (`Apple`).

```
collection('apples')()  // => Apple[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a combination of answers, using overloading in an interface declaration seemed to be the most elegant solution for my use case.

```
type Apple = {
  color: string
  taste: string
}

type Banana = {
  color: string
  length: string
}

type Carrot = {
  color: string
  baby: boolean
}

interface TypedCollectionFactory {
    (collectionName: 'apples'): () => Apple[]
    (collectionName: 'bananas'): () => Banana[]
    (collectionName: 'carrots'): () => Carrot[]
}

const collection: TypedCollectionFactory = function(collectionName: string) {
  return function get() {
    // ...
  }
}

const apples = collection('apples')()

for (const apple of apples) {
    console.log(apple.taste)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@NurbolAlpysbayev's answer is good and overloads work.

Alternatively I usually try to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) instead because they tend to compose better with unions.  For example, you can create a map from fruit name to fruit type:

```
interface FruitMap {
  apples: Apple,
  bananas: Banana,
  carrots: Carrot
}
```

and use [`keyof` and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to describe the relationship between `collectionName` and the output of `collection()`:

```
function collection<K extends keyof FruitMap>(collectionName: K): () => Array<FruitMap[K]>;
function collection(collectionName: keyof FruitMap): () => Array<FruitMap[keyof FruitMap]> {
  return function get() {
    switch (collectionName) {
      case 'apples':
        return [{
          color: 'red',
          taste: 'great',
        }];

      case 'bananas':
        return [{
          color: 'yellow',
          length: 'medium',
        }];

      case 'carrots':
        return [{
          color: 'orange',
          baby: false,
        }];
    }
  }
}
```

And that causes these to be typed correctly:

```
const appleArray = collection("apples")(); 
// const appleArray: Apple[]

const appleOrBananaArray = collection(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "apples" : "bananas")();
// const appleOrBananaArray: (Apply | Banana)[]
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is preferred and more concise if there may be more fruits.

Comment: For some reason, implementing this gives me an error `Type argument cannot be inferred from usage`.

Comment: I can’t reproduce that, so I’m not sure how to advise you.  Can you get it to occur in [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)?

Answer (score 1):

[Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) perfectly fit your use case.

```
function collection(collectionName: 'bananas'): () => Banana[]
function collection(collectionName: 'carrots'): () => Carrot[]
function collection(collectionName: 'apples'): () => Apple[]
function collection(collectionName: string) {/*... */ }

let v = collection('apples')() // Apple[]
```